# What dotted line icon in Visual Studio means

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am checking a Visual Studio project and when looking in its solution explorer I found an icon which I don't know what means.

[image]

I talk about the icon of the **logs** folder. Why is it like that, what is the purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder is not part of the project, thats why its "grayed" out. The folder exists but not included in .csproj-file, same can be seen with "bin" and "obj" -folders. If you don't want to see these you can unselect "Show All Files" from Solution Explorer:

[image]